# Upload a zf2 module from user interface (similar to wordpress plugin upload/installation)

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, upload, zend-framework2

I need to upload a ZF2 module from a form upload on the admin panel interface.

Ex :

(It basically should work like a wordpress plugin upload/installation).

I have a module Blog using a default template.
we would like the user to be able to upload a ZF2 module that will give access to a new template (with its own form/fields, actions, js, img etc). Module already created and working (db need to be manually created for now, and the module need to be manually registered in application.config.php)

When the user is uploading the module, it should :

- initialize a script that will create the table proper to its module (i guess no problem for that).
- Register the module in application.config.php (modules array). Is it possible?

It should also be able to drop the table (no problem for that) and remove the module from application.config.php when deleted.

So would it be possible ?
How can i register dynamically the module in the application.config.php?
Should i upload the module from a .rar or else?

Another thing wished is that the module should be encrypted (as the full website) so the user have no access to its content (for confidentiality reasons). So i guess i will have to manage that later and hopefully it will not be a big deal! but let's focus first on the first part ...

Any hints are welcome!

I hope i've been clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be dynamically editing your application config, that's going to cause you a lot of trouble.

A reasonable way to go about this is to build a module that grabs the ModuleManager and registers the "plugin" modules (with the appropriate checks and exception handling). I've never worked with registering modules POST-init, so I'm not sure if it's even possible or what kind of headaches it entails, but you certainly would want "plugin" modules in a separate init loop from the actual application itself.

As far as your encryption, to my knowledge, it can't be done. PHP isn't a compiled language, as such, you must provide the source in order for an application to run. Even things like rolling modules up to .phar files only obscure the source, but it's still plenty available for anyone to look at.

Comment: Yep totally agree "You don't want to be dynamically editing your application config, that's going to cause you a lot of trouble.". After 1 year i created that subject i gained a bit of experience. Therefor i gave up on such ideas ;). Thank you anyway for the answer.